# MYSQL - How to return array from first table and select from another table using that array in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

1) game_follower (stores which user is following which game):

```
___________________________
| ID  | game_id | user_id |
| 1   |  1      |  1      |
| 2   |  2      |  1      |
```

2) videos:

```
__________________________________
| ID  | game_id | content | data |
| 1   |  2      |  blah   | blah |
| 2   |  1      |  blah   | blah |
```

I'm trying to implement a twitter-style following system, but I'm having trouble writing a query that does the following:

- select multiple game_ids WHERE user_id = "1"
- from that list of game_ids, select from videos where game_id = (multiple game ids that have been selected from the first query)

I can do it with separate queries but I've been told that using multiple queries is bad for performance, so how do I do this in with one query?

Comment: "I've been told that using multiple queries is bad for performance". That's a generalization. Using (for example) *two or three* queries isn't necessarily bad for performance (though here it's not  necessary). The serious problems are if you are using "n+1" queries. That means running one query to fetch the IDs, then running the second query in a loop  - once for each ID. That will *really* kill your performance if `n` could get large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT v.game_id
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN game_follower gf ON gf.game_id = v.game_id
WHERE gf.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Brilliant, this query works perfectly! Didn't know about the INNER JOIN function!

Comment: I'm glad if this works for you. for more detail please visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Dope Monk, as you're a fresh developer, you should pay attention to Ryven's answer as it will prevent a hacker from altering the meaning of your query.  Logically, it's identical to this one.

Comment: Yeah the framework I'm using has prepared queries so its all good, thanks for the lookout Moyed!

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to do this with one query (which massivly increases speed compared to fetching the data seperately).

Answer (score 1):

```
$conn = new PDO(CONNECTION_DETAILS, $username, $pass);
$variable = 1;
$sql = "SELECT game_follower.game_id FROM game_follower ";
$sql .= "INNER JOIN videos ";
$sql .= "ON game_follower.game_id = videos.game_id ";
$sql .= "WHERE game_follower.user_id = :id";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':id', $variable, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Something like that?

Comment: This query is exactly correct, but you should modify it slightly to a prepared statement syntax.